# Show Column if Column not AutoIncrement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want query that should Return Columns which is not have auto_increment.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM test - This Query Return the following datas

Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
id  int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
content text    NO      NULL
```

I want Query that Should return columns which is not auto_increment

Ex:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM test WHERE `Extra` != 'auto_increment'
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
content text    NO      NULL
```

Comment: google "mysql information_schema"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html):

```
SELECT  column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'test'
 AND  extra = 'auto_increment';
```